# Pandas plot - Range

Tags: python, pandas

I have to plot something like this

[image]

```
data = {'begin': ['10', '15','17','25','7','8','16'],
        'end': ['15', '20', '20', '30', '15','10','19' ],
       'duration' :['5','5','3','5','8','2','3']}
```

I want the plot to contain the 'begin' and 'end' with respect to x - axis. so each and every line is a range(begin and end). Is there a way to plot this way in pandas?

Comment: You are looking for an [errorbar plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html). But first, convert your strings into numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphs and data in your question don't match, but is the following what you want to do based on the data? We have not implemented adding the circles or anything else. Please try and see.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'begin': ['10', '15','17','25','7','8','16'],
        'end': ['15', '20', '20', '30', '15','10','19' ],
       'duration' :['5','5','3','5','8','2','3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
#     print(index,row[0],row[1])
    r = patches.Rectangle(xy=(int(row[0]),int(index+1)), width=int(row[2]), height=0.4, ec='k', fc='k', fill=True)
    ax.add_artist(r)

ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.set_xlim(0,35)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. And yes, the graph i gave is just for reference as how i wanted to be. Thanks @ r-beginners !